# Passing variable number of parameters in class constructor C#

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a class `EvoObject.cs` which has a constructor defined as:

```
public class EvoObject
{
    private Object _id;
    private List<List<Int32>> _attributes;

    public EvoObject(Object _id, params List<Int32> _args)
    {
        List<Int32> _attrib = new List<int>();

        Debug.Assert(_args.Count >= 2, "Invalid attributes!");

        this._id = _id;
        _attributes = new List<List<Int32>>(_args.Count);

        for (int _i = 0; _i < _args.Count; _i++)
        {
            _attrib.Add(_args[_i]);
        }

        _attributes.Add(_attrib);
    }
}
```

in which I have used `params` for accepting variable number of parameters.

Now I have another method in another class which returns new `EvoObject` as:

```
return new EvoObject(_author, _coAuthors, _papers, _venues);
```

in which I want to relate

- `_author` with `Object _id`
- `_coAuthors`, `_papers`, `_venues` with `params List<Int32> _args`

in constructor of class `EvoObject.cs` whereas `_coAuthors`, `_papers` and `_venues`: all are lists of type `List<Int32>`

I'm getting error at line:

```
return new EvoObject(_author, _coAuthors, _papers, _venues);
```

i.e. `EvoObject does not contains a constructor that takes 4 arguments`.

How `params` can be useful here?

Comment: `params` keyword requires a single dimension array, you can't use `List<T>`.

Comment: I'm more concerned with how in the heck a `List<List<Int32>>` is going to tell you which identifiers are for what things (papers, venues, etc.).  Is that information really not important?  What use do those integers become when it's not known what they represent?  It seems like some sensible data structures could solve a lot of problems here, including the one being asked.

Comment: @David the structure `List<List<Int32>` the first list will store number of attributes that is 3 for each Object id (i.e. `_author`) and the nested list will store attribute values for each attribute (i.e. `_papers`, `_coAuthors`, `_venues`)

Comment: @Taufel: Well, if it works for you then I guess go with it.  Experience tells a very different story though.  Consider a famous quote on the subject... "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around." - Eric S. Raymond

Comment: @David: well, if you grabbed the idea I wanted to implement, you can suggest your way too, your courtesy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're missing the [] on the List declaration in your method signature in order to declare it as a parameter array.

Try `public EvoObject(Object _id, params List<Int32>[] _args)`

Comment: @DavidY--but making the change suggested by you, I got another error at the statement i.e. `_attrib.Add(_args[_i]);`. The error is "has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @DavidY--by declaring as `List<Int32>[] _args`, will `_args` be a `List` or an `Array`?

Comment: @Taufel `_args` will be an array of lists.  In that case I think you'd want `_attributes.Add(_args[_i]);`

Comment: @DStanley fine, and what about subsequent error I commented above?

Comment: @Taufel It seems like you want `_attributes.Add(_args[_i]);`.  I don't think you need `_attrib ` at all.

Comment: @DStanley yeah you right, but `_attributes` list is of type nested list which not allows to directly add list members unless to add in another list first

Comment: @Taufel `_args[_i]` is a `List<int>` There should be no problem adding it to a `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: @DStanley well, its mean there is no need to declare another `List<Int32>`, its ok